# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props') and Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I not duplicate the question bro
Let me ask new question
I get problem concerning about props and Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.
I cannot see the cause
this codes work before changing folder structure
After change file structure ,it not work
here is file structure
[image]

here is card.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  Text,
  PanResponder,
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native'
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
import moment from 'moment'

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

export default class Card extends Component {

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Animated: `useNativeDriver`']);
    this.pan = new Animated.ValueXY()

    this.cardPanResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        {dx:this.pan.x, dy:this.pan.y},
        
      ], { useNativeDriver: false }),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, {dx}) => {
        const absDx = Math.abs(dx)
        const direction = absDx / dx

        if (absDx > 120) {
          Animated.decay(this.pan, {
            velocity: {x:3 * direction, y:0},
            deceleration: 0.995,
          }).start(this.props.onSwipeOff)
        } else {
          Animated.spring(this.pan, {
            toValue: {x:0, y:0},
            friction: 4.5,
           
          }).start()
        }
      },
    })
  }


  render() {
    const {birthday, name, bio, id} = this.props.profile
    const profileBday = moment(birthday, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    const profileAge = moment().diff(profileBday, 'years')
    const fbImage = `https://graph.facebook.com/${id}/picture?height=500`

    const rotateCard = this.pan.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-200, 0, 200],
      outputRange: ['10deg', '0deg', '-10deg'],
    })
    const animatedStyle = {
      transform: [
        {translateX: this.pan.x},
        {translateY: this.pan.y},
        {rotate: rotateCard},
      ],
    }

    return (
      <Animated.View
        {...this.cardPanResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[styles.card, animatedStyle]}>
        <Image
          style={{flex:1}}
          source={{uri: fbImage}}
        />
        <View style={{margin:20}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>{name}, {profileAge}</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:15, color:'darkgrey'}}>{bio}</Text>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: width - 20,
    height: height * 0.7,
    top: (height * 0.3) / 2,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    margin: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
})
```

hoem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import Card from '../components/card'

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import database from 'firebase/compat/database'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'



export default class Home extends Component {


  
      state = {
        profileIndex: 0,
        profiles: [],
      }
  
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref().child('Users').once('value', (snap) => {
      let profiles = []
      snap.forEach((profile) => {
        const {name, bio, birthday, id} = profile.val()
        profiles.push({name, bio, birthday, id})
      })
      this.setState({profiles})
    })
  }


  nextCard = () => {
    this.setState({ profileIndex: this.state.profileIndex + 1 })
  }

  render() {
    const { profileIndex } = this.state
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {this.state.profiles.slice(profileIndex, profileIndex + 3).reverse().map((profile) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={profile.id}
              profile={profile}
              onSwipeOff={this.nextCard}
            />
          )
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import database from 'firebase/compat/database'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import Home from './screens/home'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA_AXaJ_hLC3jXMOIjaXLyktgX1t7e--FU",
  authDomain: "tinderclone-99d8e.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "tinderclone-99d8e",
  storageBucket: "tinderclone-99d8e.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "264605926507",
  appId: "1:264605926507:web:c9309a6669322ef6839d2e",
  databaseURL: 'https://tinderclone-99d8e-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/'

};


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default class App extends Component(){



    render(){
        return(
            <Home/>
        )
    }
}
```

app.js

```
import App from './app/index'
export default App
```

I follow old tutorial to build this app.
is this problem with current version ?
error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props')       
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl     
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
```

Comment: There is no `this.props = props` in the code you have posted. Where is the error coming from?

Comment: I update question bro plz check.```Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.``` may be this is problem